# Delete sub buffer from a dynamically created buffer

Tags: c++

```
char* ptr = new char[512]; // also malloc() can be used
ptr = ptr + 10;
delete[] ptr; // free() if memory allocated by malloc
```

As we know while allocating memory new and malloc saves the allocated memory size somewhere (where? Depends on compiler implementation). This saved size value is used by delete and free() while freeing the memory. 
In my case I moved the starting pointer by 10 bytes. My question is:
Is it case of memory leak?
Undefined behaviour?
Or will it try to free next extra 10 bytes after 512?

Comment: Since when `new` and `delete` are available in C?

Comment: Its an undefined behavior. On some compilers it may work and on others compiler it will throw an error. Try compiling your code on Dev C++

Answer (score 11):

That is undefined behavior, you have to free or delete the same pointer.

From *ISO/IEC 9899:201x*:

> *7.22.3.3 The free function*
>
> > *The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
> >     available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
> >     the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
> >     function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
> >     behavior is undefined.*

Regarding the undefined behavior:

> *3.4.3(1) undefined behavior:*
>
> > *behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
> >     for which this International Standard imposes no requirements*

Comment: Some explanation. What kind of undefined behaviour is possible?

Comment: @Anil8753 Well... it's undefined behavior. That means there isn't a list of "kinds" of possible undefined behavior. it's Undefined.

Comment: @Anil8753: About the best you can hope for with undefined behavior is that your program crashes immediately. On the other end of the spectrum, you can spend days or weeks in the debugger trying to figure out why memory is being subtly corrupted, during which your girlfriend leaves you and your dog dies.

Answer (score 4):

It is undefined behavior.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete

> For the first (non-array) form, expression must be a pointer or a class type contextually implicitly convertible to a pointer, and its value must be either null or pointer to a non-array object created by a new-expression, or a pointer to a base subobject of a non-array object created by a new-expression (if it's anything else, the behavior is undefined).

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behavior if you give pointers to `delete[]` that you didn't get from `new[]`. The same holds for `free()` and `malloc()` or similar pairs of allocation functions.

Likely this will lead to memory corruption and/or crashes.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is correct. I add the following:

C++ does not specify how the memory allocator works. One common way of doing it is to have fixed sized blocks (usually powers of 2). This is one mechanism for simplifying memory allocation and deallocation.

In such a system, you code grabs a block from the 512 byte pool.

Then you are trying to change that into a 502 byte and 10 byte chunk, neither of which the memory management system can handle.

Some memory management system encode data before the address returned and after the end of the block. Such system would be screwed up if it allowed what you are trying to do.